# Find the N most frequent elements in a stream

Tags: data-structures

Is there an algorithm to find the N most frequent elements in a stream (of unknown length), if it's infeasible to store all the elements in memory (like a hash map)?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way around determining the number of occurrences for each of them, especially if the stream is of unknown length and you cannot make multiple passes over it.